# Can I make iOS static library by Adobe Flash Builder (Adobe AIR)

Tags: iphone, ios, air

I want to use Adobe Flash Builder to make an iOS static library to use in native code.
Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, not possible. XCode cannot work with swc. Also no option in FlashBuilder to export native objC libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old topic, but there are some update from this side?